# Given a non-empty list of strings of the same length, how do I create a list of lists of the letters at each position in the string without using zip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, nested-lists

Given a non-empty list of strings of the same length, how do I create a list of the letters at each position in the string without using zip?

For example,

```py
Input: ["Cat", "Dog", "Fly"]
```

```py
Output: [['C', 'D', 'F'], ['a', 'o', 'l'], ['t', 'g', 'y']]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use index to get them with an easy list-comprehension:

```
l = ["Cat", "Dog", "Fly"]

r = [[j[i] for j in l] for i in range(len(l[0]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

If we convert each string to an iterator, then grabbing the `next` element from each of these iterators in a loop would do the trick

```
>>> lst = ["Cat", "Dog", "Fly"]
>>> itr_lst = [iter(s) for s in lst]
>>> [[next(itr) for itr in itr_lst] for _ in range(len(lst[0]))]
[['C', 'D', 'F'], ['a', 'o', 'l'], ['t', 'g', 'y']]
```